# Converting re.search string to date formatting

Tags: python, date, datetime, formatting

Currently we have a string of characters that we are grabbing from a paragraph with re.search, once we have this search object I'm converting it to a string and stripping the trailing and leading whitespace. This leaves me with variable a = 10162023. I'm trying to convert it to a date format so the result is 10/16/2023.

Most guides have recommended using a variance of datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y').date(). When I try to use these commands I get "myCodeMirrorResult is not defined" as a result. We already import from the datetime module along with pandas and a few other base packages such as re and glob, so I would ideally like to stay within datetime if possible.

It does seem that almost every user will enter the correct format already of 10/16/2023 after reviewing previous submissions, however we will still need that resiliency for the one or two that do not properly format their dates.

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible example to your question: input sample and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `datetime` for conversion.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

original_str = "10162023"

# Use regular expression to extract date
match = re.match(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})', original_str)

if match:
    month, day, year = match.groups()
    formatted_date = f"{month}/{day}/{year}"

    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(formatted_date, '%m/%d/%Y')

    print(formatted_date)  # Output: 10/16/2023
    print(datetime_obj)     # Output: 2023-10-16 00:00:00
else:
    print("Invalid date format")
```

Comment: So if I only the need the date then I could stop at formatted_date. and for any nonformatted date given I would assign to original_str. I added this to the test code I was using and it ran successfully.

Comment: @bShaver Yes you can do that depending on your seniors.